# React-router-dom: Clicking on Link adds the route to the Url Link indefinitely

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-router-component

After several attempts, I have managed to implement basic nested-routing with React-router-dom.
Here's the simple **project structure**:
[image]

Here are the **relevant files**:

> App.js

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import ParentComponent from "./Components/nestedComponents/ParentComponent";
import NavBar from "./Components/Shared/NavBar";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" name="Home" component={ParentComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> NavBar.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={`home/nestedComponentOne`}> Nested Component One </Link>
      <Link to={`home/nestedComponentTwo`}> Nested Component Two </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> ParentComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import nestedComponentOne from "./nestedComponentOne";
import nestedComponentTwo from "./nestedComponentTwo";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ParentComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home/nestedComponentOne" component={nestedComponentOne} />
        <Route path="/home/nestedComponentTwo" component={nestedComponentTwo} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> nestedComponentOne.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function nestedComponentOne() {
  return <div>NESTED COMPONENT 1</div>;
}
```

> nestedComponentTwo.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function nestedComponentTwo() {
  return <div>NESTED COMPONENT 2</div>;
}
```

So here's the **Result:**
[image]
If I click on **nestedComponentOne**:
[image]

If I click on **nestedComponentTwo**:
[image]

The **problem** is when I click again on **nestedComponentOne** (or Two) after the I have clicked it the first time, the route gets added to the **url string** instead of replacing it:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some update need for your code. 
[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ajtxyn?file=index.js)

#### NavBar.js

Here you forget to add slash `/` at front to link from root.

```
      <Link to={`/home/nestedComponentOne`}> Nested Component One </Link>
      <Link to={`/home/nestedComponentTwo`}> Nested Component Two </Link>
```

#### ParentComponent.js

As we removed the `Switch` from this component, so we need to get the matching information from parent router and pass the path to navigate the corresponding your nested component

```
     export default function ParentComponent({ match }) {
      return (
        <div> 
          <Route path={`${match.path}/nestedComponentOne`} component={nestedComponentOne} />
          <Route path={`${match.path}/nestedComponentTwo`} component={nestedComponentTwo} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try putting all the route in one file. Something like this:

```
<Route exact path="/home" name="Home" component={ParentComponent} />
<Route path="/home/nestedComponentOne" component={nestedComponentOne} />
<Route path="/home/nestedComponentTwo" component={nestedComponentTwo} />
```

Comment: Because I wanted the nestedRoutes to be in a file and the root route /home to be in App.js, otherwise ReactRouter will not find the path /home